# Why is Idea lint warning about missing `isPresent()` check in `orElseGet`?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Assume that I don't know if one `Optional` is empty, or if both are present. In the latter case, I always want to prefer `a` over `b`:

```
final Optional<String> a = Optional.of("1");
final Optional<String> b = Optional.empty();
if (a.isPresent() || b.isPresent()) {
  // prefer a over b
  Integer result = a
      .map(s -> s + "0")
      .map(Integer::parseInt)
      .orElseGet(() -> Integer.parseInt(b.get())); // <-- warning for b.get()
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

In my real code, Idea is warning me at this point:

> 'Optional.get()' without 'isPresent()' check.

Why is that? I am checking priorly if either `a` or `b` is present. Also, this code works as expected, the output is `10`. If I put `b = Optional.of("2")` the output is still `10` because I prefer `a`. If I then put `a = Optional.empty()`, the output is `2` as expected.

Am I doing something wrong, or is Idea's linter wrong?

Comment: It's confused by the `a.isPresent() || b.isPresent()` condition, and can't figure out that under this circumstance `b` must be present.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, actually the condition is handled nicely. IDEA just should know that `!a.isPresent()` implies `!a.map(anything).isPresent()` (which it does not know now). Also it has to look into lambdas/methodref and understand that they never return `null` (otherwise the warning is correct). It's too much analysis, but probably it will do it in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's idea that is confused here, it's internal rules probably suppose the checks to `isPresent` in the the *same* Optional chaining.

This obviously lays outside the `Optional` checks itself due to `(a.isPresent() || b.isPresent())`; it can't possible tell that there's no way to call `orElseGet` on an empty optional `b` because of those checks...

Comment: I would have assumed the linter to be smarter and be able to detect this `OR`. If I only check if `b.isPresent()`, the warning goes away. But well, thanks for confirming!

Comment: @Blacklight the correct thing to do is fill a bug for this and see what they point to; the developers there are *usually* very responsive. You might improve the tool this way

Comment: Will do, just wanted to double check my thinking first.

Comment: Checking the correctness of this code is far more complicated than just considering the logic of the `||` operator. After all, you are *not* invoking `orElseGet` on `a`, you are invoking it on the optional returned by `map`, which has been called on the result of another `map` invocation. In order to prove that the resulting optional can never be empty, it has to prove that neither `s -> s + "0"` nor `Integer::parseInt` can ever evaluate to `null`, as otherwise, `map` would return an empty optional, despite `a` being non-empty.

Comment: In Java 9, you would just write `a.map(s -> s + "0").or(() -> b).map(Integer::parseInt) .ifPresent(System.out::println);` without any `if` statements and you’re done…

Answer (score 4):

It looks like IDEAs linting is wrong in this case, but it's likely that it's to do with the complexity of deciding if `b.isPresent()` is guaranteed in the `a.orElseGet(...)` fallback.

Generally I find that if the IDE is warning be about something, it usually a good idea (*pun intended*) to fix it, as the next developer coming to look at the code will also struggle to decipher the intention behind the code.

As you're already using `Optional`, I would consider not using the `isPresent` method at all and use the api to do the work for you.  I can see two options (*pun intended*) that should satisfy the warning.

You can provide a suitable fallback if both are not present:

```
final Optional<String> a = Optional.of("1");
final Optional<String> b = Optional.empty();

// prefer a over b
Integer result = a
    .map(s -> s + "0")
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .orElseGet(() -> b.map(Integer::parseInt).orElse(0));

System.out.println(result);
```

If you never expect both to be empty, you can throw an `IllegalStateException` instead of the fallback:

```
final Optional<String> a = Optional.of("1");
final Optional<String> b = Optional.empty();

// prefer a over b
Integer result = a
    .map(s -> s + "0")
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .orElseGet(() -> b.map(Integer::parseInt).orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new));

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I like your suggestions, thanks. They indeed get rid of the warning. I actually deemed my initial code to not be too complex.. Instead of having an if-clause around the whole code, I now need an if-clause to check if the result is null (the integer was just for the example), or a try/catch block. And I don't find the code clearer or more comprehensible then. Still, good alternatives, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: fixed in IDEA 2017.3 (see [IDEA-174759](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174759)).

Yes, it's guaranteed that `b` is present at `b.get()` point. And yes, IDEA warning is wrong. The reason is that IDEA analysis in current version is not sophisticated enough to understand what's going on inside the optional chain. Note that the result also depends on the fact that `Integer::parseInt` method reference never produces `null`. Otherwise `Optional.map` may produce empty optional even if `a` is present. Consider, for example, the following code:

```
private static Integer myParseInt(String s) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

...

if (a.isPresent() || b.isPresent()) {
    // prefer a over b
    Integer result = a.map(s -> s + "0").map(MyClass::myParseInt)
                      .orElseGet(() -> Integer.parseInt(b.get()));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

In this case `b` could be absent if `a` contains non-numerical string, so here having warning is desired.

We improve IDEA static analysis constantly. In 2017.3 it will understand these constructs:

[image: IDEA 2017.3]

As you can see now warning is not displayed in original code, but displayed for nullable `myParseInt`.

IDEA 2017.3 is not yet available. However, as this feature is part of IDEA Community, you can build it by yourself using [GitHub sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) from master branch.

**Disclaimer**: I'm IntelliJ IDEA developer and I'm working to fix this case.

Comment: Thank you Tagir, much appreciated and very fast reaction. I'm not sure how many will run into such situation, but I definitely did and it's nice to see Idea constantly improving also based on developer feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking a.isPresent() and b.isPresent() in or condition. You are getting warning because it may happen that the first part of the condition turns out to be true "a.isPresent()" but b.isPresent() is false . However, due to the || condition the code inside the block will start executing. I this case b.get will fail with "NoSuchElementException".

Though according to your logic b.get() is not reachable if b is absent or empty, because you are preferring a over b. But the IDE analyzes and tells you proactively what all can go wrong or what is a bad practice in your code.

Try to do something like:

```
if(a.isPresent()){
//logic if a is there
}
else if(b.isPresent){
//logic if a not there and b is there
}
else{
logic if both are not there
}
```

Comment: I sure could have done that just to avoid the linter warning, but that's not really the point. The question was more pointed to why is Idea warning when both the if-clause and the terminal operation are known.

Comment: I have observed several times that IDEA gives warning not only on the current variable value basis but sometime it tells you intelligently what can go wrong. Here it is a combination of both as it knows that the b.get() will not be reachable but it is showing error because it knows that b is empty.